# Are there political economy models that include a "majority capture" of (protectionist) trade policy?

Tags: reference-request, international-trade, political-economy, protectionism

A highly cited model of protectionism is the ["protection for sale"](https://www.nber.org/papers/w4149.pdf) model or Grossman and Helpman. (For an [updated] evaluation of that model see for instance the *Advanced International Trade* textbook of Feenstra.)

However this model seems pretty limited to me in the view of Trump and Brexit. Modelling just lobby/industry groups carving/buying out *increased* protectionism in their own niches seems overtaken by events in which narrow democratic majorities capture the *entire* trade policy in a protectionist matter. Now (other) industry/trade groups seem to fight for niches in the opposite direction, i.e. being exempted from the overall tariffs increase; see [Apple as an example](https://economics.stackexchange.com/a/29304/6210).

Are there economic models that account for this new reality? (To some extent, this requires only a fairly trivial extension of "protection for sale", i.e. in an elevated protectionist environment, there will be groups lobbying for less protectionism, and their [anti-protectionist] niche-carving success will depend on their political clout (as a mirror of the process of buying protectionism). On the other hand, the conditions for a majoritarian capture of [increased] overall protectionism in a democracy doesn't seem so trivial.)